# Creating Linux Packages from Monodevelop 7.1

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop

I'm new to monodevelop under linux so maybe this is a stupid question but I can't find any answer to it.
On Monodevelop website on Buid & Deploy video there's an option to make tarball package right from monodevelop IDE.
Project->Make packages...
But when I go there I see only Binary Sources and Executables.
Why there`s no Tarball? Am I missed something? Autotools are installed.

[Monodevelop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKI79.png)

Monodevelop 7.1 build 1291
Debian Linux 9.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by myself.
Need to enable Makefile generation under Extension Manager->Project Import and Export